# asp-for tag helper not writing to field

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

The asp-for tag does not write to my field, if I set `received_text` with text it will show up in the web page.
The form does send the data but `received_text` is always blank.

CS:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string received_text;

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text received = " + received_text);
    }
}
```

CShtml:

```
@page "/"

@model WebApplication2.HomePage.IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<p>Send text</p>
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input asp-for=received_text />
</form>

<p>@Model.received_text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the `BindProperty` attribute applied, and it must be a property, not a field:

```
[BindProperty]
public string received_text { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does this apply to Razor Pages ? I can't find what to `using`.

Comment: Yes, exclusively to Razor Pages, in fact. You should not need any using.

Comment: Still doesn't work, added using `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` do I need some app service ?

Comment: also needs [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] to work

Comment: That's only for GET requests, obviously. You said form, so I assumed POST. Really unless its a special circumstance where you need the data to be part of the URL, such as a search, you should always use POST, there's security implications to allowing data from the query string to be bound.